# Constraints on explicit specialization of a member of a class template

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-specialization

According to [[temp.expl.spec]/16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.expl.spec#16):

> A member or a member template of a class template may be explicitly specialized for a given implicit instantiation of the class template ...

After some tests, I found that the specialization should match the member in the implicit instantiation of the class template, meaning they should be the same type. For example,

```
template<class T> struct A {
  void f(T);
  static T i;
};

template<> void A<int>::f(int);     // ok 
// template<> void A<int>::f(char); // error

template<> int A<int>::i;     // ok
// template<> char A<int>::i; // error
```

**Where does the standard specify such constraints?**

Comment: If you have the *same* `T` in `template<class T>` and `void f(T)`, how could they be different `T`s?

Comment: In addition to Evgeny: Instancing `struct A` for type `int`, you get a method `void f(int);` defined. If you want to implement `template<> void A<int>::f(char) { }` - there is no such method defined in `struct A<int>`. If you need this, you have to specialize `template <class T> struct A` completely, e.g. `template <> struct A<int> { void f(char); };` Now, you can (must) implement `void A<int>::f(char) { }`. The alternative: Make the method in quest a template of its own: `template <class T> struct A { template <class U = T> void f(U); }`.

Comment: imho @evgeny should make the comment an answer, because there is little to add, it can just be put in different words, eg: the implicit instantiation `A<int>` already has a `f(int)`, you cant change its signature by specialization, only provide different implementations.

Comment: @Evgeny Intuitively, explicit specialization means the entity may have totally different meaning. For example, the definition of an explicitly specialized class is unrelated to the definition of a generated specialization.

Comment: This is a language-lawyer question, so please answer it using references from the standard.

Comment: The method `f(T)` isn't a template itself - it's part of `template struct A`. You cannot specialize something which isn't a template, can you. (Sorry, this is no "language lawyer" comment as well.)

Comment: @xskxzr, in my intuition the same `T` cannot denote different types, note that `f(T)` is not a template.

Comment: @Scheff See the text I quoted, the standard indeed uses the wording "a **member** or a member template of a class template **may be explicitly specialized**".

Comment: @Evgeny The key is not whether `T` can denote different types. It is why the specialization should match the declaration in the primary template.

Comment: I understand this: You may specialize a single member e.g. `void A<int>::f(int)` (instead of specializing `struct A<int>`). But this doesn't mean you can change the signature of `f()` as `f()` itself is just a member but no template.

Comment: Remember that the original idea of a template was to set types as parameters. It is not a pure placeholder to insert arbitrary types at every individual occurrence.

Comment: @Scheff That is what I asked, why we cannot change the signature of a non-template member? Maybe I'm asking what is the exact meaning of specializing a non-template member.

Comment: You cannot specialize a non-template. (...and I can imagine that you don't find any quote in standard for this.) It's just that you can specialize templates (and nothing else).

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comment of Evgeny:

Instancing `struct A` for type `int`, you get a method `void f(int);` defined.

If you want to implement `template<> void A<int>::f(char) { }` – there is no such method defined in `struct A<int>`.

To achieve this, you could specialize the whole `struct A` for `int`.

The alternative is (as already shown in [answer of user846834](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51839325/7478597)) to make the method in quest a template itself.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct A {
  void f(T);
};

template <>
void A<int>::f(int) { std::cout << "void A<int>::f(int) called.\n"; }
#if 0 // ERROR
void A<int>::f(char) { std::cout << "void A<int>::f(char) called.\n"; }
#endif // 0

template <class T>
struct B {
  void f(T);
};

template <>
struct B<int> {
  void f(char);
};

void B<int>::f(char) { std::cout << "void B<int>::f(char) called.\n"; }

template <class T>
struct C {
  template <class U = T>
  void f(U) { std::cout << "void C<T>::f(U) called.\n"; }
};

template <> template <>
void C<int>::f(char) { std::cout << "void C<int>::f(char) called.\n"; }

int main()
{
  A<int> a; a.f(0);
  B<int> b; b.f(0);
  C<int> c; c.f('0');
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
void A<int>::f(int) called.
void B<int>::f(char) called.
void C<int>::f(char) called.
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bb4835e1685f925)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In the examples of the link you have given, it is only the non-type template parameters (`X1, X2`) that were specified to be of different type than T. 
And only they can be specified as different. The type template parameters need to be the same as the specialization.

```
template<class T> struct A {
  void f(T);
  template<class X1> void g1(T, X1);
  template<class X2> void g2(T, X2);
  void h(T) { }
};

// member template specialization
template<> template<>
  void A<int>::g1(int, char);           // X1 deduced as char
template<> template<>
  void A<int>::g2<char>(int, char);     // X2 specified as char
```

Comment: Why is the type template parameters (more generally, the type of a member) need to be the same as the specialization?